# Check input file size using Flash

Tags: html, flash, file-upload

I have a multipart html form with a file input element and would like to check the size of the selected file before uploading. I can access the file path using the value attribute, however is it possible to pass that path to a swf and have the swf return the file size or is this blocked by the flash sandbox? Are there any existing projects that already do this? I'd like to avoid replacing my file input element with a flash uploader if possible.

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea - contacting with a SWF would require JavaScript, which can be easily modified by the user. You'd better create the entire uploader in Flash.

Comment: It may not be a good idea but not for the reason you mention. As with anything client side (javascript, flash, etc), it can always be circumvented so if security is an issue you need to re-validate on the server side.

Comment: You're right, for example an advanced user may track the SWF's upload actions with an HTTP sniffer and then try to reproduce them with modified headers, so he can send a file bigger than expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing file names and accessing it via Flash is security risk. Flash does support a FileReference API, but it requires user input in order to work.